Gesture authentication with Amazon Rekognition possible?
I want to authenticate a user based on their captured hand gesture. Don't care about accuracy since it's a second factor authentication.
Is it even possible with Amazon Rekognition. Or is there any other better solution for this use case.
I've explored Amazon Rekognition and I understand it's primary use case is facial authentication. I  have a requirement where I have to authenticate the hand gesture of the user. I see there is a API to detect objects in an image available. Which means it can potentially detect a hand? But there is no compare object API that I could find.
